# Does http need ssl certificate?

Tags: http, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I have 2 microservices in different server and i tried to hit api using http from one to other. it get me like timeout response [server not response]. And i tried hit api using https and it get me error like "you need certificate".
My question is does http need ssl or not ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP no, HTTPS yes. Many blanks to satisfy system...

Comment: but why i get timeout response ? , btw : i can get response while i am using telnet and didnt work with curl command

Comment: Who knows.... Firewall perhaps? L3 routing mistake?

Comment: HTTP/3 requires TLS.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: *"HTTP/3 requires TLS."* - true, but then it will also be a `https://` URL and not a `http://` URL. So HTTP/3 requires TLS because HTTP/3 requires HTTPS.